# client registration error while running app

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the sample studio project of IBM for notification and tried running it on myphone it says failed "Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server."
I have simply just downloaded the zip file and ran using using eclipse and later installed as android application using android studio

```
Authentication failure in realm 'PushAppRealm': Please check the credentials [project PushNotifications]
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: 
File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: 
FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: 
/apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E:
 Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E:
 File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E: 
 Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E:
File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E:
Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E:
 File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: 
 FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught:
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: 
File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: 
File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: 
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[project PushNotifications]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E:
 File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport:
 FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/ [project PushNotifications]
```

and Android log error

```
Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":500,"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.","invocationContext":null}
06-23 12:44:30.922 23562-23618/com.PushNotifications E/NONE:               [/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/init] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
06-23 12:44:30.942 23562-23618/com.PushNotifications D/NONE: Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server.
```

and

```
WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://HARI:10080/PushNotifications/authorization/v1/clients/instance
06-23 12:44:30.282 23562-23953/com.PushNotifications W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "HARI": No address associated with hostname
```

What might be the problem here?

[change of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTU3a.png)

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "HARI":.
Looks like you have a URL that cannot be reached. Correct it first

Answer (score 0):

Find the wlclient.properties file in your Android project and verify that the HOST property is the IP address of your machine and not the computer name, which will not get resolved correctly.

Comment: u mean the ip address of my pc or the local host?

Comment: i have added a fimage can u direct me which address to add... and my ip address is 10.0.0.16 and when i change the ...the logcat says connection refused

Comment: If you're running the server on your workstation then those are the same. Use your IP

Comment: i found out that my ip address is a different one than this i change the image for reference am i doing it correctly and when i keep the ip address and deploy the adapter i get "Runtime synchronization failed. Cannot deploy adapter to runtime"

Comment: sometimes the adapter gets successfully deployed and then when i run the project on the mobile developemnt server i get "a server error is detected"